# Not getting firebase access token

Tags: firebase, error-handling, firebase-cloud-messaging, access-token

Firebase messaging error in http server, but works well in https server.

; FirebaseError: Messaging: The required permissions were not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked).

Do we need https server to send the notification from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK is supported only in pages served
>   over HTTPS. This is due to its use of service workers, which are
>   available only on HTTPS sites.

[More Information here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

Good luck!